# java, how to close statement which is used in different method?

Tags: java, sql

I have two static methods in two classes: Account and FunnyDB. in FunnyDB I have a method which is used in Account to retrieve object from database. I am wondering if it is possible to somehow close statement (stmt) in the FunnyDB from Account method. Also, if it is not really possible, what are the consequences of leaving statement not closed? These are my methods:

FunnyDB:

```
/**
 * Returns ResultSet from query to get data to create object. Identufy data by id
 *
 * @param tableName Name of he table to search. Use getClass().getSimpleName().
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
public static ResultSet getObjectResultSetById(String tableName, int id) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        // gets object's details from database
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); //<-- I WANT TO CLOSE THIS PARAMETER
        String sql = "SELECT * \n"
                + "FROM " + tableName + " \n"
                + "WHERE " + tableName.toLowerCase() + "_id = " + id;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //TODO: Closing rs and stmt? .close().
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FunnyDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Account:

```
/**
 * Returns object found by given ID.
 *
 * @param id Object ID.
 * @return Object from database.
 */
public static Account getAccountFromDatabaseById(int id) {
    Account account = null;
    try {
        ResultSet rs = FunnyDB.getObjectResultSetById("Account", id);
        // create object to return
        while (rs.next()) {
            account = new Account(rs.getInt("account_id"), rs.getString("account_name"), rs.getString("account_type"), Currency.getCurrencyFromDatabaseById(rs.getInt("currency_id")), rs.getDouble("start_amount"), rs.getDouble("balance"));
        }
        rs.close();
//close stmt?????
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Currency.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return account;
}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: make `stmt` as class variable.

Comment: You must close the statement in method scope.  You'd be smart to not return a ResultSet.  Better to map it and close it in the same method scope as Statement that created it.

Comment: rs statement connections all should be closed so that the db connection is released.Everytime you make a connection to DB ,DB will keep the connection open even if you close your app.until DB's connection cleaner kicks in. Based on DB server configuration there is a limit to open connections. Once you exceed that limit DB will not take any other request.Then only way out will be to restart the DB.Also different DB's allocate some memory per connection .So more opened connections means your DB server will consume more memmory.

Comment: That is really helpful explanation, thanks! I'll try to use map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a class responsible for closing a `Statement` that is different than the one that created it is a bad idea.  What if the calling code forgets to close it?

The `FunnyDB` class should be responsible for closing the `Statement`; it created it.  To do this, it must read the `ResultSet` itself, creating the `Account`, so that it's completely done with the `ResultSet`.  This way, there is no problem closing the `ResultSet` and the `Statement` before it returns.

Move the code that creates the `Account` with calls to the `ResultSet` into `FunnyDB`'s `getObjectResultSetById` method.  Have that method return the `Account` instead of the `ResultSet`.  Close the `ResultSet` and `Statement` there.  You might want to rename it `getAccountById`.  You may also want to use a "try with resources" statement if you're using Java 7+.  You can have the `ResultSet` and `Statement` closed automatically.  If you are stuck with Java 6 or below, use a `finally` block to `close` them, to ensure that everything is closed before returning.

The `getAccountFromDatabaseById` in `Account` doesn't need to manipulate the `ResultSet` at all; it just needs to use the `Account` returned by `FunnyDB`.

Comment: I had that before, but I have few different classes like  `Accoun` and this is why I wanted to separate these two things. Anyway thank you!

Comment: *I had that before, but I have few different classes like  `Account` and this is why I wanted to separate these two things, so I can use the FunnyDB method in each of different classes. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ResultSet as a parameter to getObjectResultSetById, so getAccountFromDatabaseById can close it.

Never *EVER* leave a resource open. When talking about databases, leaving a resource open could mean that at one point or another you will get a 'cursor limit exceeded' or something like that and this is hard to debug.

Also, as a general rule, always close your resources in a `finally` block. This way, you ensure that your resources will be closed even if your method throws an exception.

Comment: Using `try-with-resources` is another option as it will call the AutoCloseable `close()` method on any object that implements it.

Comment: I can not agree more. Using try-with-resources (from Java 7) is a much cleaner option.

Comment: Your answers should consider good practices, not workarounds as you suggest. See @rgettman answer to see something about this.

Comment: so try-with-resource would close that statement? Something like that? `try (ResultSet rs = FunnyDB.getObjectResultSetById("Account", id)) {//...}`